# How can I dodge / combine both geom_point and geom_boxplot with two factors

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, geom-point

I'm looking to add point data so that is sits adjacent to a box in a boxplot. When I run the below example, the point data does not separate for each fill factor. Is there a way to add point data that corresponds to the box when plotting 2 factors in a boxplot? Can this also be added so it is to the left of the box rather than on top of it?

```
Group<-c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B")
Value<-c(2,1,6,4,2,5,3,6,8,1,10,2,2,3,4,6)
Round<-c("Round 1","Round 1","Round 1","Round 1","Round 2","Round 2","Round 2","Round 2",
     "Round 1","Round 1","Round 1","Round 1","Round 2","Round 2","Round 2","Round 2")
data<-as.data.frame(cbind(Group,Value,Round))
data$Round<-as.factor(data$Round)
data$Group<-as.factor(data$Group)
data$Value<-as.numeric(data$Value)
str(data)

ggplot(data,aes(Group,Value,fill=Round))+
 geom_point(aes(colour=Round))+
 geom_boxplot(width=0.5,position = position_dodge(width=0.7))+
 labs(fill= "Round",x="Group",y="Value")
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use `position_dodge` for the points like this:

```
ggplot(data,aes(Group,Value,fill=Round))+
  geom_point(aes(colour=Round), position = position_dodge(width = 0.9))+
  geom_boxplot(width=0.5,position = position_dodge(width=0.7))+
  labs(fill= "Round",x="Group",y="Value")
```

Output:

[image]

You can change the `width` to change the position of the points.

Another option is using `position_jitterdodge()`:

```
ggplot(data,aes(Group,Value,fill=Round))+
  geom_point(aes(colour=Round), position = position_jitterdodge())+
  geom_boxplot(width=0.5,position = position_dodge(width=0.7))+
  labs(fill= "Round",x="Group",y="Value")
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: To add up to this answer:
If you want to see the points that lie in the boxplot area, you could use alpha in your boxplot() environment
`geom_boxplot(width=0.5,position = position_dodge(width=0.7), alpha = 0.5)`

Answer (score 4):

As Quinten says, one would normally use `position_dodge` here. However, you can't do this if you want the points to sit just to the left of the boxes, since you would need to **nudge** and **dodge** at the same time, which isn't currently an option. Instead, you can nudge the groups in two layers:

```r
ggplot(data,aes(Group, Value, fill = Round)) +
 Map(\(r, d) geom_point(aes(colour = Round), subset(data, Round == r),
    position = position_nudge(x=d)), r = levels(data$Round), d = c(-0.33,0.02)) +
 geom_boxplot(width = 0.5, position = position_dodge(width = 0.7))
```

[image]

To have your points and boxes in the same color, use `shape = 21` inside `geom_point` and remove the `color = Round` aesthetic mapping:

```r
ggplot(data,aes(Group, Value, fill = Round)) +
  Map(function(r, d) geom_point(data = subset(data, Round == r),
      shape = 21, position = position_nudge(x = d), size = 2), 
      r = levels(data$Round), d = c(-0.33, 0.02)) +
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.5, position = position_dodge(width = 0.7)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#6699FF","#FFFFFF")) +
  theme_gray(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

Or, if you don't want the points outlined (but then the white points are difficult to see)

```r
ggplot(data,aes(Group, Value, fill = Round)) +
  Map(function(r, d) geom_point(aes(color = Round), 
                       data = subset(data, Round == r),
                       position = position_nudge(x = d), size = 2), 
      r = levels(data$Round), d = c(-0.33, 0.02)) +
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.5, position = position_dodge(width = 0.7)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#6699FF","#FFFFFF")) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#6699FF","#FFFFFF")) +
  theme_gray(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

Comment: Allan, this is wicked code. I thought I knew R, and stand corrected. Would you care enlighten me (and maybe even lesser versed people) what "r" and "d" are?? I can see those are arguments to your anonymous function, but I don't see where you are specifying them. And what is `c(-0.33, 0.02)`? This unnamed argument seems so out of the blue.

Comment: (I realise you haven't named any of the arguments in geom_point, that's probably why I'm confused. I would probably not recommend that (?)

Comment: @tjebo you're right, I probably wouldn't use this code in production. It's now possible to add a `list` of layers to a ggplot, so you can add an `lapply` or a `Map` to a plot with `+` and it will work. I have used the `\(r, d)` as opposed to the `function(r, d)` for brevity. I should name the arguments in `Map` for clarity. The levels are needed to specify which group of points I'm dealing with in each iteration, and the `c(-0.33, 0.02)` are the amount of dodge each group needs to get them to sit to the left of their respective bars.

Comment: I knew about the list bit (I'm using this a lot to be honest) and the function replacement \ (not using at all, as I don't find this easy to read;) Thanks for clarifying the names - it seems like a miracle to me that the mapping was correct, given that you basically used `...` ?

Comment: @tjebo the `...` are passed to the anonymous function in the order you write them, so if I have defined `\(r, d)`, the first item after the function will be interpreted as `r` and the second as `d`.

Comment: yeah, makes sense - I think I'm generally more on the cautious side and tend to explicitly name arguments, given lots of annoying bugs not only in package writing :)

Comment: That worked thanks! I'd like to change the colour of my points so they match my boxes (See below). Is there anyway I can get scale_manual_colours to match the points as well as the boxes?         
ggplot(data,aes(Group, Value, fill = Round)) +
  Map(\(r, d) geom_point(aes(colour = Round), size=2,subset(data, Round == r),
                         position = position_nudge(x=d)), r = levels(data$Round), d = c(-0.33,0.02)) +
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.4, position = position_dodge(width = 0.7))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#6699FF","#FFFFFF"))+
  theme_bw()

Comment: You can change `color` to `fill` inside `geom_point` and use `shape = 21` _outside_ of `aes` in `geom_point` (otherwise your white points will be difficult to see). An alternative is to add `scale_color_manual(values=c("#6699FF","#FFFFFF"))` to your plot in addition to `scale_fill_manual(values=c("#6699FF","#FFFFFF"))`, though the white points will be hard to see.